# createCache fails in non-static method

Tags: ignite

I am creating a cache with a CacheStoreFactory implementation and a CacheStoreSessionListener. If I set the CacheConfiguration with these fields and then call createCache but in an INSTANCE method I get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.CacheException: class
>   org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to validate cache
>   configuration (make sure all objects in cache configuration are
>   serializable): LongCache

In a static method, this does not occur. This can be easily reproduced by modifying the CacheJdbcStoreExample.java in examples. This is happening under Ignite 1.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you declared the factory or the listener as an anonymous class. Anonymous classes always contain reference to the parent class (`LongCache` in your case). So if the factory is serialized in the context of `LongCache` instance, this instance is also serialized. In case of static method this instance doesn't exist, therefore everything works.

I would recommend to convert anonymous classes to private static classes. This will give you more control on what is serialized.

Comment: Excellent, that solved the issue, thanks for the feedback.